# Google Tag Manager - CookeDomain not set properly for a subdomain

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, subdomain, google-tag-manager

I am working on setting Google Tag manager to one of our subdomain. Parent domain or the base domain already has the google universal analytics code setup and its working fine.

For subdomain, we took an approach to create separate analytics code and link into GTM and use the tracking code. While doing so, i see the _ga cookie is set to the base domain and not the subdomain.

**Example domain:**

**Base domain**: companyname.com

**Sub domain**: shop.companyname.com

I tried to set the cookie_domain variables to auto, but still the cookie is set at the top level domain. We are using GTM code snippet for including the code into the application.

Is there any configuration missing to make the cookie set at the exact subdomain? Can any one of you suggest what is to be corrected, it will be helpful.

Also the cookie value is set as "GS1.1.xxxxxxxxxxx.1.1.1619336094.0". What does GS denotes here? I have seen the value as GA in other apps.

Thanks in Advance
Regards
Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set `cookieDomain : auto` if you want manage they as separate domains.

Here a good article that can help you: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.simoahava.com/amp/analytics/cookie-settings-and-subdomain-tracking-in-universal-analytics/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michele. I initially tried without adding cookieDomain and still got the same result. Cookie (_ga_XXXXXXXXXX) was set at the base domain and not to the current sub domain. I have referred to few other blogs and artilces but couldn't able to find the configuration to set cookie at sub domain with GTM code.

Comment: Show your GA tag configuration, pls

Comment: HI, here is the snapshot of the configuration 
https://pasteboard.co/JZ7exKN.png

Answer (score 0):

If you set the cookie domain to "auto", then Google code sets the cookie for the highest accessible "level" from the domain i.e.., **companyname.com**. It also means the cookie is available on all the subdomains for your url.

So try setting cookie domain to your sub domain and test it.